# How to divide 2n members of the club into disjoint teams of 2 members each, when teams not labelled?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am doing this and getting $\sum_{i=0}^{2n-2} \frac{(2n-i)!}{2!(2n-i-2)!}$ but the answer given is $\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}$ I even tried to get this by simplifying my result, but not getting the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their answer: imagine lining up everyone in a row and then pairing up adjacent people. There are $(2n)!$ ways to line everyone up, but different line-ups can produce the same teams. To account for this overcounting, divide by $n!$ for the number of ways to arrange the $n$ teams in a row, and divide by $2$ for each pair to account for swapping the order of the members of each pair.

In your answer, you probably meant $\prod_{i=0}^{2n-2} \binom{2n-i}{2} = \prod_{i=0}^{2n-2}\frac{(2n-i)(2n-i-1)}{2} = \frac{(2n)!}{2^n}$, which comes from choosing the first pair, choosing the second pair, and so on. But here, you are accounting for the order that the teams are chosen. (Recall the problem states the teams are not labeled.) So, you should divide by $n!$. This agrees with their answer.

Comment: I got your point just two doubts I have got $\prod_{i=0}^{2n-2} \binom{2n-i}{2}$ because if I take 2n in place of 2n-2 I get negative value in factorial, am I correct? Second I am still not clear on that order and labeling stuff that you told, what does they mean by teams not labeled?

Comment: @Ankit Sorry, you are right about the indexing. Regarding labeling, it just means that if, for example, you have four people A, B, C, D, then there are two outcomes (A,B) (C,D) and (A,C) (B,D). The ordering within the teams ((A,B) is the same as (B,A)) does not matter, nor does the ordering of the teams ((A,B)(C,D) is the same as (C,D)(A,B)).

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis leads to the $\frac{2n!}{2^n}$ part of the answer, but overlooks the overcount due to the order of the groups.

As a direct method, consider simply starting with all orderings of the $2n$ members ($2n!$ options) and making groups by first $2$, next $2$ etc. This overcounts in two ways

- the order of the members in the pairing
- the order of the pairs

Dividing out these overcounts gives the result $\dfrac{2n!}{2^nn!}$

Comment: I just have one doubt what do they mean by labeling, and how does this impact the question?

Comment: *Labelling* means that the teams are distinguishable by name, e.g. *Ants*, *Bees*, *Crickets*, etc. So you and me in *Ants* is different from you and me in *Bees*. If they were unlabelled, you and me being together in **any** team is  the same, hence the division by $n!$

Comment: There is another question which says that there are n kingdoms and 2n champions, each kingdom getting 2 champions the ways in which this can be done is given by $\frac{2n!}{2^n}$ we have not divided by n! because it matters as to which kingdom you belong? Am I right?

Comment: @Ankit Exactly so, the kingdoms are distinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the problem of arranging letters in the word MAMA. It is $\binom{4}{2}$,  because it enumerates all ways to get 2 disjoint subsets froma set of 4 numbers and compare to the case when Ms and As are of different colors: you need to mulfiply it by 2!. The first case is your situation.

Answer (score 0):

There is in fact a direct formula for this:
**Formula**: The number of ways in which $mn$ different items can be divided into $m$ groups each consisting of $n$ objects, with order not important is given by: $$ \frac{(mn)!}{(n!)^{m}\times m!}. $$ In your problem, with $m=n$ and $n=2$ we have $\frac{(2n)!}{(2)!^{n}\times n!}$ which is the answer!

Answer (score 0):

How did you proceeded??

I am getting the same answer as given.

My way is

For choosing 2 members out of 2n,, the ways are $2n\choose 2$

Again choosing 2 members out of 2n-2 ,the ways are $2n-2\choose 2$

Proceeding this way you will get

$2n\choose 2$.$2n-2\choose 2$.$2n-4\choose 2$...$2n-(2n-4)\choose 2$.$2n-(2n-2)\choose 2$.$2n-2n\choose 2$

On solving you will get $\frac {(2n)!}{2^nn!}$

That is the solution

Comment: Why downvote ??,,, Am I not getting the right way or Did you not get the solution after solving ???  Please guide & give reasons for downvotes...   This thing demotivates me !!!!

Comment: I haven't downvoted but when I solved it, it does not give n!, so may be that is why somebody must have done.

Comment: Should I paste a picture of my solution ,,, because I am getting all the parts of solution